# Is it possible to implement derived units of SI system using user-defined literals?

Tags: c++11, user-defined-literals

I would like to overload user defined literals so that it will allow to perform some physical calculations, e.g

```
auto force = 5_N;         // force in newton
auto distance = 6.8_m;    // distance in meters

auto resultingEnergy = force * distance;    // expected result in joules
```

How can it be achieved ?

Comment: You'd need strong typedefs for values (or just new types) and overloaded operators. Literals only produce values of some given type, being a syntax sugar.

Comment: You can look at [Boost.Units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_units.html) for inspiration, and basically make user-defined literals return the appropriate Boost.Units types.

Answer (score 1):

You can define some new types (or use boost units as mentioned above),

A user defined solution could be similar to:

```
#define DECLARE_UNIT(UnitName) \
struct UnitName { \
    UnitName(const long double val) noexcept : val_(val) {};\
    long double val_ = 0.0; \
};

DECLARE_UNIT(Joule);
DECLARE_UNIT(Newton);
DECLARE_UNIT(Meters);

const Newton operator""_N(const long double n) noexcept {
    return Newton(n);
}
const Meters operator""_m(const long double m) noexcept {
    return Meters(m);
}

const Joule operator*(const Newton& newtons, const Meters& meters) noexcept {
    return newtons.val_ * meters.val_;
}


int main() {
    auto force = 5.0_N;
    auto distance = 6.8_m;
    auto energy = force * distance; // of Joule type
}
```